# Getting list of objects from excel to Dataprovider using Poiji

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I've got a problem with passing objects to Testng dataprovider.

The main problem:
I'm using https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji to read testing data from Excel file(1 row is a 1 new object of class Person).

It returns a List of Person objects, but for the dataprovider it should be Object[][]. How can I convert it?

Xlsx file:

```
firstName | secondName
-----------------------
John      | Deer
Eric      | Boots
```

Person class:

```
public class Person{

    @ExcelCellName("firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @ExcelCellName("secondName")
    private String secondName;
```

Dataprovider:

```
  @DataProvider
    public Object[][] readExcel() throws Exception {
        List<PersonalApplicant> res = Poiji.fromExcel(new File(("persons.xlsx")), Person.class);
        return res;

    }
```

Error:

```
Incompatible types.
Required:
java.lang.Object[][]

Found:
java.util.List
<com.example.package.Person>
```

Comment: https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-list-to-array-java/

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you declared your function to return Object[][] and you return a list. 
Declare the function to return only **Object[]** and then use **.toArray()** when returning.

```
    @DataProvider
    public Object[] readExcel() throws Exception {
        List<PersonalApplicant> res = Poiji.fromExcel(new File(("persons.xlsx")), Person.class);
        return res.toArray();

    }
```

Comment: There is an error - "Data provider must return Object[][] or Iterator<Object[]>"